# Powershell download/install fonts "deploy"

Tags: powershell, batch-file, installation, deployment, fonts

I testing new powershell/batch download and install fonts oneliner, but with no luck so far (errors every time in cmd, under PS is OK)...
I believe there is problem with quotes somewhere

point is simple oneliner runable from batch

```
POWERSHELL -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& {$fonts=@('Roboto','Ubuntu') | ForEach-Object {(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('https://fonts.google.com/download?family=$_', '$env:TEMP\$_.zip'); Expand-Archive -Force '$env:TEMP\$_.zip' -DestinationPath '$env:TEMP\FONTS'}}"
```

thanks

Comment: _but with no luck so far..._ -> What does that mean? Do you get any errors? Do you get an unexpected outcome? Please be more specific! What happens when you run the command in a Powershell?

Comment: yes erorrs under cmd, PS is OK

Comment: Than can you please add these errors?

Comment: ok, but if you put this code to your cmd you cant get same result?
Exception calling "DownloadFile" with "2" argument(s): "An exception occurred during a WebClient request."
At line:1 char:50
New-Item : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name '$env' does not exist.
At C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive\Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive.psm1:31
8 char:32

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using single quotes in your command the [variable substitution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-string-substitutions?view=powershell-7.2#variable-substitution) mechanism of Powershell will not work. So you have to use double quotes an mask them with a backslash. This worked for me:

```
POWERSHELL -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& {$fonts=@('Roboto','Ubuntu') | ForEach-Object {(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile(\"https://fonts.google.com/download?family=$_\", \"$env:TEMP\$_.zip\"); Expand-Archive -Force \"$env:TEMP\$_.zip\" -DestinationPath \"$env:TEMP\FONTS\"}}"
```

Comment: yes, I knew it would be something small... :)  thanks